# Cloud foundry service down

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have an issue with postgres database in cloud foundry. Created service using cloud foundry market place. Application worked good until yesterday, and today not able to connect to database or ping it. I am not sure where to check service logs or how to restart postgres service in cloud foundry. Any one have some ideas please respond to this thread. Thanks. I can see below error in application logs.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
```

Tried to ping database host IP address, but shows down.

Comment: Well, one thing you could try is to unbind the service from your app and bind the service back to your app. For most service brokers, this will generate new credentials and connection info. If for some reason the IP/connection info changed, that would allow you to get the most recent info. One other, would be to review the application security groups assigned to your org. Double check that the IP address for your database server is allowed by the ASG's (default is to deny all, so that IP has to be specifically allowed). If it's not, that would block traffic. Only your admin could fix though.

Comment: If my previous comment doesn't help, you need to reach out to whomever is managing your Cloud Foundry marketplace and ask them for help. They are really the only ones that will know what has changed and what might be impacting your connections.

Comment: I did unbind database service, restarted and again binded database service back. Still the same. I could not ping that dB instance, I also did try creating another Postgres instance and pinged, it worked.

Comment: You need to talk to your Operations Team, or whomever is running these services. Only they can help you understand what's happened here.

Comment: Yeah talking to operations team, and I am doing a bit of research my side. Thanks Daniel Mikusa.